# Visual Studio Starter Kit for development of dnn skin and dnn module?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, module, dotnetnuke-7, starter-kits

I want develop my dnn modules and skins with vs starter-kit.   Where I can download dnn7 Starter Kit for development of dnn skin and dnn module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now You can download [dnn starterkit](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/downloads/get/117645) for visual studio